# Heat Equation - Reducing the boundary condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, heat-equation

I should solve the **heat equation:**

$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial t}u(t,x) = \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2} u(t,x) $$

with boundary conditions $u(t,0)=u_0, \: u(t,1)=u_1$ and initial condition $u(0,x)=u(x).$

**My Solution:**

Separation of Variables gives:
$$ u(t,x)=w(t)y(x) \Rightarrow \frac{\partial }{\partial t}u(t,x) = \dot{w}(t)y(x); \: \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2} u(t,x) = \ddot{y}(x)w(t)$$

From that we conclude:

$$ \frac{\dot{w}(t)}{w(t)} = \frac{\ddot{y}(x)}{y(x)}  \overset{!}{=} - \lambda $$

Furthermore:

$$ w(t)=c_1 e^{-\lambda t}; \; y(x)=c_2cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+c_3sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x) $$

W.L.O.G.:  $y(0)=u_0=y(1)=u_1=0$, from which follows, that:

$$ u(t,x) = c_1 e^{-(n\pi)^2t} c_3 sin(n\pi x)$$

**My Question:**

Why can I suppose without loss of generality:  $y(0)=u_0=y(1)=u_1=0$?

There is a hint written: If $u(x,t)$ solves the heat equation so does $u(x,t)+a+bx.$ Use this to reduce the boundary conditions to the case $u_0=u_1=0.$

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assume W.L.O.G ${u_0=u_1=0}$. The hint is there for that reason. Notice that letting ${u(x,t)=y(x,t)+u_0+(u_1-u_0)x}$, would give that ${u(0,t)=y(0,t) + u_0\Rightarrow y(0,t)=0}$, and ${u(1,t)=y(1,t)+u_1\Rightarrow y(1,t)=0}$. And plugging ${u(x,t)}$ into the PDE will show that ${y(x,t)}$ also satisfies the PDE. So now you can simply solve the PDE for ${y(x,t)}$ (which has nice homogeneous boundary conditions just as we'd want), and sub back in to ${u(x,t)=y(x,t)+u_0+(u_1-u_0)x}$ to find the general solution for ${u(x,t)}$